# mongoDB aggregation: $addToSet then $sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to sort unique values in arrays in multiple fields from a mongoDB collection (with the nodeJS driver).

a small dataset :

```
[{
    "_id" : "5c93db3dd0184516406013f7",
    "filters" : {
        "genres" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "9CXBYc4qP8sqcNMZ5",
                "fr" : "Art Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract Art",
                "de" : "Abstrakte Kunst",
                "it" : "Arte astratta",
                "es" : "Arte Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "subjects" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "3QjL6YSfmuY6NFHGG",
                "fr" : "Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract",
                "de" : "Abstrakt",
                "it" : "Astratto",
                "es" : "Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "type" : {
            "_id" : "CYK2WcepkJsy5xXMo",
            "fr" : "Gravure au carborundum",
            "en" : "Carborundum etching",
            "de" : "Carborundum Radierung",
            "it" : "Incisione carborandum",
            "es" : "Grabado al Carborundum"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "5c93db3ed0184516406013f8",
    "filters" : {
        "genres" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "9CXBYc4qP8sqcNMZ5",
                "fr" : "Art Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract Art",
                "de" : "Abstrakte Kunst",
                "it" : "Arte astratta",
                "es" : "Arte Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "subjects" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "3QjL6YSfmuY6NFHGG",
                "fr" : "Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract",
                "de" : "Abstrakt",
                "it" : "Astratto",
                "es" : "Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "type" : {
            "_id" : "CYK2WcepkJsy5xXMo",
            "fr" : "Gravure au carborundum",
            "en" : "Carborundum etching",
            "de" : "Carborundum Radierung",
            "it" : "Incisione carborandum",
            "es" : "Grabado al Carborundum"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "5c93e19ed018451640601da6",
    "filters" : {
        "genres" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "9CXBYc4qP8sqcNMZ5",
                "fr" : "Art Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract Art",
                "de" : "Abstrakte Kunst",
                "it" : "Arte astratta",
                "es" : "Arte Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "subjects" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "3QjL6YSfmuY6NFHGG",
                "fr" : "Abstrait",
                "en" : "Abstract",
                "de" : "Abstrakt",
                "it" : "Astratto",
                "es" : "Abstracto"
            }
        ],
        "type" : {
            "_id" : "KfGWEHL2pAto8nfze",
            "fr" : "Gravure",
            "en" : "Etching",
            "de" : "Radierung",
            "it" : "Incisione",
            "es" : "Grabado"
        }
    }
}]
```

the result of my query (with `lang = 'en'`):

```
{
  "subjects": [
    {
      "_id": "3QjL6YSfmuY6NFHGG",
      "fr": "Abstrait",
      "en": "Abstract",
      "de": "Abstrakt",
      "it": "Astratto",
      "es": "Abstracto"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3QjL6YSfmuY6NFHGG",
      "fr": "Abstrait",
      "en": "Abstract",
      "de": "Abstrakt",
      "it": "Astratto",
      "es": "Abstracto"
    }
  ],
  "genres": [
    {
      "_id": "9CXBYc4qP8sqcNMZ5",
      "fr": "Art Abstrait",
      "en": "Abstract Art",
      "de": "Abstrakte Kunst",
      "it": "Arte astratta",
      "es": "Arte Abstracto"
    },
    {
      "_id": "9CXBYc4qP8sqcNMZ5",
      "fr": "Art Abstrait",
      "en": "Abstract Art",
      "de": "Abstrakte Kunst",
      "it": "Arte astratta",
      "es": "Arte Abstracto"
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "_id": "CYK2WcepkJsy5xXMo",
      "fr": "Gravure au carborundum",
      "en": "Carborundum etching",
      "de": "Carborundum Radierung",
      "it": "Incisione carborandum",
      "es": "Grabado al Carborundum"
    },
    {
      "_id": "KfGWEHL2pAto8nfze",
      "fr": "Gravure",
      "en": "Etching",
      "de": "Radierung",
      "it": "Incisione",
      "es": "Grabado"
    }
  ]
}
```

The pipeline for the aggregation :

```
[
    { $unwind: '$filters.subjects' },
    { $unwind: '$filters.genres' },
    { $group: {
      _id: null,
      subjects: { $addToSet: '$filters.subjects' },
      types: { $addToSet: '$filters.type' },
      genres: { $addToSet: '$filters.genres' },
    }},
    { $unwind: '$subjects' },
    { $unwind: '$genres' },
    { $unwind: '$types' },
    { $sort: {
      [`subjects.${lang}`]: 1,
      [`types.${lang}`]: 1,
      [`genres.${lang}`]: 1,
    }},
    { $group: {
      _id: null,
      subjects: { $push: '$subjects' },
      types: { $push: '$types' },
      genres: { $push: '$genres' },
    }},
    { $project: {
      _id: false,
      subjects: '$subjects',
      types: '$types',
      genres: '$genres'
    }}
]
```

Instead of getting sorted arrays of unique values as so :
`[A, B, C, D, ...]`

I get sorted arrays with non unique values as so :
`[A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C, D, D, D, ...]`

Making the `$addToSet` grouping useless.

Any idea on what I got wrong ?

Comment: Also post sample collection and the output

Comment: I can see all the three `generes` are same in the sample data. But in output you have shown two. `$addToSet` should make it to single `generes`. Or I am interperting something wrong
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that each `$unwind` is going to create a copy of the document with a single array element from the array you're unwinding. You have the following:

```
...
{ $unwind: '$subjects' },
{ $unwind: '$genres' },
{ $unwind: '$types' },
...
```

So, first you're unwinding `subjects` which produces a documents for each element in `subjects`, which we will call `subject`. Thus we have a document for each `subject` which themselves contain the arrays `genres` and `types`. On unwinding `genres` next, each `subject` document gets unwinded to contain an element `genre` from `genres`. This gives use `genres.length` copies of each `subject`--that is, each subject is duplicated based on how many `genres` there are in the array. A similar situation occurs when unwinding `types`.

In short, you're duplicating your data on every `$unwind` call.

To illustrate with a simpler example:

```
// Doc:
{
    ints: [1, 2],
    alpha: ['a', 'b', 'c']

}

// Pipeline:
[
    { $unwind: "$ints" },
    { $unwind: "$alpha" }

]

// After unwinding "ints":
[
    { ints: 1, alpha: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
    { ints: 2, alpha: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }

]

// After unwinding "alpha":
[
    { ints: 1, alpha: 'a' },
    { ints: 1, alpha: 'b' },
    { ints: 1, alpha: 'c' },
    { ints: 2, alpha: 'a' },
    { ints: 2, alpha: 'b' },
    { ints: 2, alpha: 'c' }
]

// Result: 3 duplicates of each value in "ints", 2 duplicates of each value in "alpha".
```

To resolve this, a couple of options immediately come to mind:
 1. You can `$unwind` an array, `$sort` it, and `$group` the results to `$push` the elements back into an array, repeating for each array individually, one at a time. Note that you would need to use the `$first` operator to grab only one copy of each duplicated array when grouping.
 2. You can change your last `$group` pipeline stage to use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` operations.

There are likely other options available to you, but either of the above should suffice for something quick.

Comment: Thank you for the tips about data duplication ! It solved my issue !